# gvim startup slow: huge GUI delay

Tags: ubuntu, vim, gvim

`vim` starts up quickly. 
`gvim` takes ages, with or without loading plugins.

The `--startuptime` option shows:

```
733.162  467.301: starting GUI
733.945  000.783: reading viminfo
25801.849  25067.904: GUI delay
```

Where is that huge GUI delay coming from?

This is on Ubuntu 12.04, running Gnome with XMonad. Vim is `vim-gnome 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1`

(I also asked this on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383786/gvim-startup-slow-huge-gui-delay) )

Note: I uninstalled the global menu:
`sudo apt-get autoremove appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt`

After a restart, it looks like the huge GUI delay is gone.

Comment: Is it `vim-gnome` or `vim-gtk`?

Comment: Edited answer to include vim version. It looks like uninstalling the global menu worked: gvim is still starting up nice and snappy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling the Ubuntu global application menu as mentioned in my answer above fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have your vim auto start **WinManager** or **NerdTree** at the time of vim/gvim start?
If yes, I think that might take long time to load the directory construction.

I've met the Vim start too slow problem, and after auto loading directory construction closed, everything just fine.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I don't use either of those. As mentioned in my comment above, it looks like the problem was the Ubuntu global menu.

Comment: What version about your gvim? Does it installed by `apt-get install` or **built by sourcecode**. If it was built by source code. You can tried my configuration: `./configure --enable-gui=gnome2 --enable-cscope --enable-multibyte --enable-xim --enable-fontset --with-features=huge --enable-pythoninterp=yes --enable-rubyinterp=yes --enable-python3interp=yes --with-compiledby=Marslo`

Comment: And, you should install some gnome libs first. The steps can be found here: https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig#compile-vimgvim-by-source-code-on-linuxubuntu

Comment: My vim/Gvim works fine on my Ubuntu. My OS is Ubuntu 13.10